# Which pattern would you use to implement an "early-termination" logic?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

In my project, I have several occurrences that needs verification on value using multiple conditions. Since satisfying at least one of these "conditions" is enough, and each conditions require heavy computation power, I usually try from the most lightweight one to the heaviest one, until any of them succeeds. To implement this, I usually use a pattern like below.

```
bool success

do {
    if (success = condition_1()) break
    if (success = condition_2()) break
    ...
} while (false)

if (!success) {
    cleanup()
} else {
    proceed()
}
```

**The point is that I want to use the "break" statement**, but to do this, *I have to add a dummy do-while loop*, which actually does nothing but provides context for the break statement. I doubt if doing so is okay. Would anybody have a recommendation for a better pattern on this situation?

These are the patterns I've tried as workarounds.

- Separate the condition checks as a function, and using return statements instead of break => This is good, but sometimes I don't want to make too many functions.
- Declare a common flag that indicates success, and run each condition if the flag is set false => This requires evaluation of if statements on each step, although their impacts on performance are minuscule.

Comment: _"I have to add a dummy do-while loop, which actually does nothing but provides context for the break statement. I doubt if doing so is okay."_ - that's one of the warts of writing in a C-derived language that we all just-get-used to - but there are alternatives (besides `goto`), such as moving the inner-logic to a separate function and using `return` instead of `break` and handling clean-up in the outer function, for example.

Comment: Remove the `do`, `while`, and `break` statements. Reverse the sense of the `if` statements. Put a semicolon after the last `if`. That gives you early-out, since the `if` chain terminates after the first failed condition. The only downside is indentation. Some people, and most code-editing software, will insist on indenting the `if` statements. But it's more readable if you omit the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take, some of which can be heavily language-depended:

1. Create collection of functions (potentially anonymous/lambda ones) and iterate it. Pseudocode:

   ```
   funcs = [() -> condition1(), () -> condition2() ...]
   success = false
   for f in funcs:
      success = success || f();
      if(success):
        break;

   ... cleanup
   ```
2. A lot of languages support [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of logical conditions so if one you use is among those then you can just rely on short-circuiting:

   ```
   success = condition1() || condition2() || ...

   ... cleanup
   ```
3. For more complex scenarios you can look into implementing some flavor of [pipeline](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/design-patterns-implementing-pipeline-design-pattern-824bd2d42bab), i.e. you turn your `condition`'s into steps of the pipeline, for example each step accepts the following one and decides if it needs to execute it or not. Something like is done in ASP.NET Core with [request handling middleware pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: The chain of responsibility pattern is another option although it's almost the same as the pipeline pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a regular if:

```
if (condition_1() || condition_2()){
  cleanup()
} else {
  proceed()
}
```

The evaluation of the if will stop as soon as a value returns true and the rest of the expression will not be evaluated. In other words, if condition1() returns true, condition2() will not be called.

Disclaimer: This is true in most programming language, but I have heard of at least one language (WinDev) where this was not the case at some point in time, so if you use an exotic language, check your doc.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this approach because it makes debugging and troubleshooting much harder because the lack of a named local to store the return-values you can't tell which of `condition_1` or `condition_2` failed or succeeded (VS only recently added the ability to see anonymous/discarded function-call return-values, and I haven't seen that feature in any other debugger I've used).